# Annular springs collection

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

[image]

if we have  collection of springs in parallel with different softness values between two rigid plates and affecting force, also the distances between the springs are equal  >>>> I know that if the softness of the springs are equal we can reduce the collection into one spring with a softness equal to sum of the softness or (K total=n*K) and effecting point in the middle but in this structure the situation is different ....... so my question is what is the value of the equal softness and where is the effecting point???

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a small displacement, the force from each of the springs will be proportional to the spring constant. If we assume that the plate remains flat (so all displacements are the same) then the point where all these forces appear to act is found from the weighted sum of the positions and the spring constants. For this you don't even need the spacings to be constant; if the position of spring with constant $k_i$ is $\mathbf{r_i}$ - it is simply found from

$$\mathbf{r}_{eff} = \frac{\sum_i k_i \mathbf{r}_i}{\sum_ik_i}$$

at which point the effective spring constant is just the sum of all the spring constants

$$k_{eff} = \sum_i k_i$$

If you apply the force at a point $\mathbf{R}\ne\mathbf{r}_{eff}$, then there will in general be an angle to the plate. This means that the displacement will now be proportional to the distance, $d_i(x) = d_0 + ax$ where $d_0$ is the displacement at $x=0$ and $a$ is some non-zero constant to be found.

The torque about the center (which has to be zero) is given by

$$\begin{align}\Gamma &= \sum F_i x_i \\
&= \sum k_i d(x_i) x_i \\
&= \sum k_i (d_0 + a x_i) x_i\\
&=0\end{align}$$

$$\Rightarrow d_0 \sum k_i x_i + a \sum k_i x_i^2 = 0\tag1\\
$$

We also have the total force:

$$F = \sum k_i d_i = \sum k_i (a x_i + d_0)$$

$$
\Rightarrow d_0 \sum k_i + a\sum k_i x_i - F = 0 \tag2$$

This gives us two equations in $a$ and $d_0$ which you can solve; when that is done, you have your expression for $d_0$ as a function of $F$: this gives you the effective spring constant:

$$k_{eff} = \frac{\sum k_i x_i \sum k_i x_i - \sum k_i x_i^2 \sum k_i}{\sum k_i x_i^2}$$

As a sanity check, if we take 4 springs of the same k, and we put them equally spaced, then we find

$$k_{eff} = k \left(\frac{\sum x_i \sum x_i -n \sum x_i^2}{\sum x_i^2}\right) = 4 k$$

exactly as we would have expected.

Comment: really, the plate remains flat because it is rigid but it will incline as in the picture ..... and really this picture isn't the suitable one for my question because if there are for example 6 springs how will it be ..... still the qualitative spring constant is the sum of the constants of the springs and the effecting point is still the same in the middle or what .... I maked my calculations and there was unknown mistake for me but  I think it should be in the effective constant or in the effecting point of it.......??

Comment: If you push down at the point I calculate above the plate will be flat. If you push down in the middle there will be a torque balance equation that gives you the angle. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: that is right I am depending on torque balancing and also there must be force balancing also .... what I am trying to calculate is if I have a collection of springs with different softness values between to rigid plates as in the new photo (those are my variables ).... and I want to calculate the deflection for each spring .......

Comment: really for my calculations in excel the values were right just in one condition which is k1=k2=.....=k6

Comment: thank you very much Floris..... it was very helpful for me..... but one last thing....may you provide me with  resource of this equations you had wrote....????

Comment: I derived them from first principles... so I have no reference to give you sorry.